# Representations of $SU_q(n)$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, von-neumann-algebras, quantum-groups

I am searching for a classification of all irreducibel representations of the quantum group $SU_q(n)$ for general $n$. Can someone give referenced or some statements about this? Moreover does one has a explicit presentation of $SU_q(2)$ in the von Neumann algebraic setting, sometimes also written as $L^{\infty}(SU_q(n))$? Thanks a lot.